# Find string from javascript code with selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I´m testing web page and i need to assert code fragment in javascript code, such as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//img.xxxx.com/u/14/p42449.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.ptag_params = {
zone: "homepage",
customerId: "Your customer ID",
siteType: "Site Type",
};
</script>
```

I´ve tried use

```
<tr>
<td>verifyHtmlSource</td>
<td>*42449*</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

but I don´t see any response, in log only

```
[info] Executing: |verifyHtmlSource | *42449* | |
```

What am i doing wrong???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code above looks good but since it's not based on css it shouldn't matter with order.

```
<tr>
    <td>verifyElementPresent</td>
    <td>//script[contains(@src, 'p42449.js')]</td>
    <td>*ga.js</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeAttribute</td>
    <td>//script[contains(@src, 'p42449.js')]@src</td>
    <td>source</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${source}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

The selenium command you've used there isn't really the best for what you're trying to do. All that will do is check that somewhere within the entire html of the page, the number 42449 appears, doesn't guarantee it will find it in the script fragment you want to see it in. in regards to the logs, you won't see any more output than you have in the log with a verify command because it will just pass or fail depending on if it finds that number.

If you need to confirm this element exists and would like to see some output containing it in the logs your best bet would be a combination of verifyelement and storelement Example below

**Script**

```
<tr>
    <td>verifyAttribute</td>
    <td>css=script@src</td>
    <td>*42449.js</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeAttribute</td>
    <td>css=script@src</td>
    <td>source</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${source}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

**Log Output**

```
[info] Playing test case Untitled
[info] Executing: |verifyAttribute | css=script@src | *42449.js |
[info] Executing: |storeAttribute | css=script@src | source |
[info] Executing: |echo | ${source} | |
[info] echo: //img.xxxx.com/u/14/p42449.js
[info] Test case passed
```

The only thing you'd need to be careful with is if you have multiple script tags on your page, you'd just need to amend the locator with an nth value if it's the second or third script etc.

Comment: Might be better to just do a verifyElementPresent:
//script[contains(@src, '42449.js')]

Answer (score 1):

Finally, i´ve used

```
<tr>
    <td>storeHtmlSource</td>
    <td>buscaPixelesVen</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyEval</td>
    <td>javascript{storedVars['buscaPixelesVen'].indexOf(&quot;42449&quot;,0)&gt;0}</td>
    <td>true</td>
</tr>
```

and it works. Maybe is not the best solution, but is enough.

Thanks in any case

Comment: This doesn't look very pretty. Did you try my example above?